# python: indexerror about 'Trending #Hashtags'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing groklearning python courses and I met a problem:

The question is as below:

*the capitalisation and punctuation in hashtags is inconsistent. You decide to write a program to read in tweets, normalise any hashtags present, and print out a tally of frequencies. Hashtags should only include words starting with #. All punctuation should be removed from the end of a hashtag, and the letters should be converted to lowercase. For instance, #Python! should be normalised to #python, and #Today_I_Learned... should be #today_i_learned.*

The output is meant to be

```
Tweet: #Python is #AWESOME!
Tweet: This is #So_much_fun #awesome
Tweet: 
#so_much_fun 1
#awesome 2
#python 1
```

And my code is as below

```
from collections import Counter
import string
tweet = input('Tweet: ')
lis = tweet.lower().strip().split()
lis_hash = []

while tweet:
  for i in lis:
    i = i.rstrip(string.punctuation)
    if i[0] == '#':
      lis_hash.append(i)
  tweet = input('Tweet: ')
  lis = tweet.lower().strip().split()

ans = Counter(lis_hash)
for i in ans:
  print(i,ans[i])
```

My code does work on the example but when I was trying to submit, the error appeared as **'Testing a long example. Your submission raised an exception of type IndexError. This occurred on line 9 of your submission.'** where line 9 refers to 'if i[0] == '#':' in my code.

I have no idea of this error, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try printing i with the following input string `test , tost`. You will see that in the second iteration `i` will be an empty string(`''`), and trying to index an empty string(`''[0]`) will result in the given error.

So you need `if i != '' and i[0] == '#':` or something of the like.

Comment: 'if i != '' and i[0] == '#': ' this actually works!!

Comment: but why does it not work when I type ' if i[0] == '#' and i != '':'?  Why does the order matter?

Comment: Because if the first element of an ```or``` statement is false, the second element won't get evaluated. Therefore if i is an empty string and it's the first element of the ```or``` statement, it will still give you the error.